# Internet dropping out on Ubuntu

Tags: linux, networking, ubuntu, wireless-networking

How do you diagnose your Internet dropping out under Ubuntu 16.04?

I have a Dell 5520 laptop, and it's Internet (both wired and wireless) randomly stops working for seemingly no reason. I don't think it's my router, as no other device on my network exhibits this problem. Also, simply turning my wifi off and on, or unplugging and then re-plugging the ethernet cable immediately fixes it, so it seems like it's some local bug with DHCP or the networking driver.

As you can imagine, this is quite frustrating, and breaks a lot of automated systems that need Internet access.

How do I diagnose this? Running `cat /var/log/syslog |grep -i network` finds:

```
Nov 30 08:15:47 localhost dhclient[3646]: receive_packet failed on enxd481d72559eb: Network is down
Nov 30 08:15:47 localhost NetworkManager[29467]: <info>  [1512047747.9144] device (enxd481d72559eb): state change: activated -> unmanaged (reason 'removed') [100 10 36]
Nov 30 08:15:47 localhost NetworkManager[29467]: <info>  [1512047747.9360] dhcp4 (enxd481d72559eb): canceled DHCP transaction, DHCP client pid 3646
Nov 30 08:15:47 localhost NetworkManager[29467]: <info>  [1512047747.9360] dhcp4 (enxd481d72559eb): state changed bound -> done
Nov 30 08:15:47 localhost NetworkManager[29467]: <info>  [1512047747.9367] dns-mgr: Writing DNS information to /sbin/resolvconf
Nov 30 08:15:47 localhost NetworkManager[29467]: <info>  [1512047747.9567] manager: NetworkManager state is now CONNECTED_LOCAL
Nov 30 08:15:48 localhost systemd[1]: Starting Network Manager Script Dispatcher Service...
Nov 30 08:15:48 localhost systemd[1]: Started Network Manager Script Dispatcher Service.
Nov 30 08:15:48 localhost NetworkManager[29467]: <error> [1512047748.7027] platform-linux: do-change-link[23]: failure changing link: failure 19 (No such device)
Nov 30 08:15:48 localhost NetworkManager[29467]: <warn>  [1512047748.7030] device (enxd481d72559eb): failed to disable userspace IPv6LL address handling
Nov 30 08:15:48 localhost NetworkManager[29467]: <info>  [1512047748.7033] devices removed (path: /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.6/0000:05:00.0/0000:06:02.0/0000:3d:00.0/usb4/4-1/4-1:1.0/net/enxd481d72559eb, iface: enxd481d72559eb)
Nov 30 08:16:03 localhost NetworkManager[29467]: <warn>  [1512047763.7603] device (eth0): failed to find device 24 'eth0' with udev
Nov 30 08:16:03 localhost NetworkManager[29467]: <info>  [1512047763.7620] manager: (eth0): new Ethernet device (/org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/Devices/8)
```

Clearly, that shows there's some sort of network problem occurring, but I'm not sure what. How do I figure out what's going on here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My hard drive died, forcing me to re-install onto a fresh drive. Since Dell doesn't publish the image for their proprietary version of Ubuntu, I reinstalled stock Ubuntu 16.04, and everything works fine. So it seems Dell's custom Ubuntu distro is buggy and/or has bad drivers in it, which can't even be fixed by running a normal apt-get update.

Answer (score 1):

Due to the grepping for network some relevant lines from the syslog are missing, but it looks like your USB ethernet device is disappearing and coming back:

```
devices removed (path: /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.6/0000:05:00.0/0000:06:02.0/0000:3d:00.0/usb4/4-1/4-1:1.0/net/enxd481d72559eb, iface: enxd481d72559eb)
...
(eth0): new Ethernet device (/org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/Devices/8)
```

This is no networking problem, but a USB hardware problem. Is there a USB hub involved? Other USB devices taking too much power? Broken USB cable? Something along those lines.

Comment: I'm using the [USB-C to Ethernet adapter](http://www.dell.com/en-us/work/shop/accessories/apd/470-abnd?c=us&l=en&s=bsd&cs=04&sku=470-ABND) that came with the laptop. However, this happens even when I disable the ethernet and use wifi.

Comment: Can you post logs from the dropouts on wifi? They should look different.